# Array from datas during a while

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an array with the following datas into my while:

```
while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $data1 = $fetch['DEB_Sum'];
  $data2 = $fetch['DEB_PaymentMethod'];
}
```

How can I do this please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to `SELECT` just the columns you want, and then use `fetchAll`:

```
$data = $query->fetchAll();
```